# Can quotes be nested in Windows?

Tags: windows

I want to modify a shortcut to use a different CPU affinity, e.g.:

```
cmd /c "start /affinity 7 path\program"
```

It works fine, until `path` or `program` contains spaces.

Then, quotes surrounding `path\program` would be needed, nested inside the other quotes.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need the root quotes in this case. Simply set the shortcut target to:

```
cmd /c start /affinity 7 "path\program"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use backslashes as escape character :

`cmd /c "start /affinity 7 \"path\program\""`

> Note that backslashes are only special
>   if they are in front of a quote or a
>   backslash

**Update :**
Officially, the solution above should work, but in practice it seems it doesn't.

I tried without the backslashes and, although it sounds strange, it works for me (Win XP).

`cmd /c "start /affinity 7 "path\program""`

Comment: that results in
> "\"path\program\"" could not be found...

Comment: You're right, sorry... Did you try without the backslashes ? I just tried it and it works for me (on XP) : `cmd /c "start /affinity 7 "path\program""`

Comment: it does not really work as intended. All consecutive parts of string are just concatenated, may them be quoted or no (`"a b"c` becomes `a bc` as one argument), and if you'll add a space to "path\program", you'll see how it fails.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either - for shortcuts. When I use Start->Run... I don't seem to need any quotes at all. Weird. I'm using WinSever2k3. Using a second shortcut to be executed via `start` ignores the affinity setting, so I guess I have to add `program` to my path. But thanks for trying, I'll check it on my Win XP at home, too.